# Using combobox on a edit page with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, crud

I have two tables, tblPlayer(PlayerID, PlayerName,PlayerTeam(int) ) and tblTeams (TeamID, TeamName)

On a PHP page I have a function to find the selected player, function is as follows,

```
function find_selected_player() {
    global $sel_player;
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $sel_player = get_player_by_id($_GET['id']);
    } else {
        $sel_player = NULL;
    }
}
```

my other function as follows,

```
function get_player_by_id($player_id) {
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM tblPlayer ";
    $query .= "WHERE PlayerID =" . $player_id ." ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result_set = mysql_query($query, $conn);
    confirm_query($result_set);

    if ($player = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
        return $player;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

So on the form to edit I can get all values like

```
<input type="text" name="PlayerName" value="<?php echo $sel_player['PlayerName']; ?>" />
```

But...:) when I try to fill up a combo box with the reverse way I am stuck there. When adding something this works like a charm but $sel_player['PlayerTeam'] is giving me only ID :(

```
<?php include "conn.php" ?>
<?php include "function.php" ?>
<?php find_selected_player() ?>
<h2>Edit: <?php echo $sel_player['PlayerName'] ." ". $sel_player['PlayerLname']; ?></h2>
<form action="player.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
   <td>Name: </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="PlayerName" value="<?php echo $sel_player['PlayerName']; ?>" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Lastname:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="PlayerLname" value="<?php echo $sel_player['PlayerLname']; ?>" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Team:</td>
   <td>
        <?php
$sql = "SELECT TeamName, TeamID FROM tblTeam";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo '<select name="TeamName"><option>';
echo "Choose a team.</option>";
echo '<option selected>' . $sel_player['PlayerTeam']  . '</option>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $team_name= $row["TeamName"];
    $team_id = $row["TeamID"];
    echo "<option value=\"$team_id\">$team_name</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
        ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" /></td>
       <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</form>
<?php ob_end_flush() ?>
<?php include ("footer.php") ?>
```

Comment: You don't echo pure HTML, just escape it

Comment: You have a typo : `$team_adi`should be `$team_name`

Comment: What does the function `get_player_by_id()` return? That is where you should be getting the name of the team from.

Comment: Kacey, I need it to match the ID with TeamName from tblTeam. Actually my naming on variables are not so good, PlayerTeam holds an id which needs to matched with TeamID

Comment: Where in your code do you call the `find_selected_player()` function?

Comment: I have added it in the code, and updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

                        $sql = "SELECT TeamName, TeamID FROM tblTeam";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql);
                        $player_id = $_GET['id'];
                        $current_team = mysql_query("SELECT
                                        tblteam.TeamID,
                                        tblteam.TeamName,
                                        tblplayer.PlayerID,
                                        tblplayer.PlayerTeam,
                                        tblplayer.PlayerName
                                        FROM
                                        tblplayer
                                        INNER JOIN tblteam ON tblplayer.PlayerTeam = tblteam.TeamID
                                        WHERE PlayerID = $player_id LIMIT 1 ");
                        $my_row = mysql_fetch_array($current_team);
                        ?>
                        <select name="TeamName">

                            <option selected value="<?php echo $my_row['TeamID']; ?>"> <?php echo $my_row['TeamName']; ?> </option>
                            <?php
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                $team_name= $row["TeamName"];
                                $team_id = $row["TeamID"];
                                echo "<option value=\"$team_id\">$team_name</option>";
                            }
                            echo "</select>";

                            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update your code to use MySQLi_*, or PDO. I've gotten you started here. Try this out and see how it works for you.

```
function getPlayerByID($pid = '')
{
    global $conn;

    if($pid == '')
        return false;

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblPlayer WHERE PlayerID = '$pid'", $conn);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1)
        return $row;
    else
        return false;
}

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

$sel_player = getPlayerByID($id);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT TeamName, TeamID FROM tblTeam");

$select = '<select name=""><option>Choose a Team</option>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $team_id = $row['TeamID'];
    $team_name = $row['TeamName'];

    $selected = $team_id == $sel_player['PlayerTeam'] ? 'selected' : '';

    $select .= '<option ' . $selected . ' value="' . $team_id . '">' . $team_name . '</option>';
}

$select .= '</select>';

echo $select;
```

Comment: Kacey, thank you. Probably that will work, I need to learn about MySQLi and recode my study i guess. I am pretty new to PHP (probably you'd say that with the question I came up with:) ) and need to learn more to implement what you said. As for now, having errors like  `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in...`

Comment: @cevizmx I've updated my answer so that the mysql_* functions resemble your current ones. Try it with that, and see how that works out for you.

Comment: this is works, but does not reflect the selected value. Combo box reflects "Choose a team" but not the saved team in the datebase

Comment: If you put `echo $sel_player['PlayerTeam'];` under `$sel_player = getPlayerByID($id);` what does it give you?

Comment: Gives back the id, as i have mentioned PlayerTeam actually is holds id :( btw, what does ? do `$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';` could not find it on Google :)

Comment: Then a function to get the player by ID is completely irrelevant. You already have the ID using the $_GET method. You can CHECK that the ID exists, but there's no point in having a function that grabs the ID, and then returns the ID.

Comment: @cevizmx I've updated my answer again. All I did was change `$team_name` to `$team_id` in the `$selected` variable. Try that out.

Comment: been laughing what I've accomplished :) but this takes me to ground zero again:( And also this again gives me Choose a team option selected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28756/discussion-between-cevizmx-and-kacey)

Answer (score 0):

```
$team_adi should be $team_name
```

Change:

```
echo "<option value=\"$team_id\">$team_adi</option>";
```

to:

```
echo "<option value=\"$team_id\">$team_name</option>";
```

Comment: Well, thanks :) but still, I have a problem with `$sel_player['PlayerTeam']` as it gives me an ID, need to get the name from tblTeams table